# I can’t give you anything but love

Tags: phrases, personal-pronouns

As I understand it, personal pronouns are often used  in English, but this phrase doesn't contain a pronoun "my", i.e. "... but my love." Why is it so? Will it be the excess word in this sentence?

> **I can’t give you anything but love.**

Comment: If you give love to someone, it _has_ to be your own (unless you are passing on a message from a third party, as in the idiom "Give him my love").  We can, for example, sign a letter "All my love", but we don't _have_ to use the personal pronoun to specify that the love is ours.

Comment: @KateBunting Any reason your comment isn't an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *give love* to someone, it is by definition yours (unless you are passing on an affectionate message from a third party, who has asked you to "Give him/her my love").

We sometimes use the personal pronoun (for example, signing a letter "All my love, [name]"), but it isn't necessary.

Comment: Compare 'I can't give you anything but money'. It's *probably* my money, but it just might be someone else's.